# Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found

Tags: upgrade

I updated Magento to the latest version via Magento connect , it was success but after the update I get blank screen for admin and frontend.

When I put

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE']) || true) {
  Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

at my index.php

I get below error:

**Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in**
how can i solve it please help i want urgent fix .

Comment: What happens when you copy all the new core files to your applications. Either via rsync or ftp?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the file `app/Mage.php` exists and that you have this in your `index.php` file

```
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
....
require_once $mageFilename;
....
```

Comment: thanks but why it happens when updated via magneto connect ,